# Angular argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have this code,

```
{{(((product.price - product.new_price)/product.price)*100).toFixed(0 | currency: 'Rp ' : 'symbol' : '1.0-0')}}% OFF
```

It returns percentage of my product discount, If i use `ionic serve (ng serve)` it works with no issue but when i try to build my app in production it says:

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'number'.

**Note:**

1. I am using `Ionic 4 with Angular ~8.1.2`
2. Data coming from API link

**any idea?**

Comment: First, when you have calculation this long for the value you want to bind, you should save it as a var in your component instead of calculating in the template directly. It's less readable and more annoying to debug/test. Second, is the error message correct? Sure it runs when you serve, but should it? are you using a string somewhere where you expect a number? Lastly, I recommend using the `--aot` flag whenever you run serve. It will give you compile time errors, meaning it will be closer to an actual build (I'm simplifying a lot, but here is the doc: https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

The problem was `toFixed` part

```
.toFixed(0 | currency: 'Rp ' : 'symbol' : '1.0-0')
```

after removing it now it build my app in production with no error.

final code :

```
{{
    ((
        (product.price - product.new_price)/product.price
    )*100)
}}% OFF
```

Hope it helps.